# C++ saving info such as tree in a file

Tags: c++

I'm intrested in creating programs of games and such which learns while playing and saving the information for further use. For example a tic tac toe game where the program saves evry game it won or lost and creates a tree of some kind that store the information of the game and save it in a file when the program is being quit. The problem i'm having is how to save a tree in a file efficently. Any suggestions?
Thenx in advance.

(I'm programming in c++)

Comment: Knowing (a) what is supposed to be *in* your tree you're wanting to save, and (b) what ideas you've coded up so far, will likely get you a *lot* more information (and may even solve your problem in the process).

Comment: You'll have to flatten the tree and do the reverse which is to take a flat file and construct a tree from it.

Comment: I'd suggest taking a look at the [boost serialization library](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/serialization/doc/index.html), it will require a bit of work, but should solve the problem if you're using your own data structure.

Answer (score 2):

One option is to use [Boost Property Tree](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/doc/html/property_tree.html), that can help you to load and store tree structures into the xml files (and several other formats are supported as well). This library is well documented, you can find many examples directly on the web-site

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is also called serialization. There are [quite a few hits](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%2b%2b%5D%20tree%20serialize) here on StackOverflow for serializing trees in C++. I suggest you look into [JSON](http://json.org/) and [YAML](http://www.yaml.org/) as possible formats. There are multiple C++ libraries for both.

Answer (score 1):

I think I'd try nogard's answer first (I've upvoted his). However, if you find that you don't get much value out of the runtime support (ie. the tree in memory) and it only really serves as a serialization/unserialization mechanism, I'd suggest trying out [pugixml](http://pugixml.org/). It's a very complete, very performant, yet simple to integrate, xml library.

Furthermore, to aide in the in-memory part, I've had good success with simply composing trees out of STL containers (it's simpler than it seems). I've found that different trees can have different requirements (ie. pointer to parent, no pointer to parent, etc.) If the tree has a large number of nodes, these pointers per node can add up. And, if you don't have a use for them, given the way you're iterating through your tree, then it'll just be waste.

Answer (score 1):

If your tree is a stl container, such as a map, then you can create a functor for each element that serialises its data to a string, or directly to file, then walk the tree - using an algorithm like [for_each](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/for_each/) which will call the functor for you.

That's simple. Re-creating the tree is a matter of reading the elements from the file, turning them back into objects and adding them to a new tree structure. You'll need to keep the keys to the tree, not just the values.